# Image to 8-bit based Byte Array

Tags: java, graphics, arrays, bytecode, lcd

I'm developing interface for [Graphic LCD 128x64](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/serial-graphic-lcd-12864-st756567-ctrl-black-and-white-p-287.html), the interface is generated in run time as Bitmap, my target is to convert this bitmap to Array of Bytes, there are a lot of functions found online to convert image to Array of Bytes but none of them convert it to the desired one, there is an application that took an Bitmap and returns its Bytes represented array but its code is not available, here is the app [BMP2GLCD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bmp2glcd/) any help ?

Comment: We can't decompile software for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but its code is not available

It is available [here.](http://bmp2glcd.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/bmp2glcd/) A [tarball](http://bmp2glcd.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/bmp2glcd/src/?view=tar) is also available.

If it's on sourceforge, it's likely open-source.

Parsing the C++ or turning it into a JNI-compatible system(latter may be worthwhile due to low-level access by the C++ code) is up to you.